# overflow:hidden обрезает тень - как поправить?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, css3

Приветствую. Сайт на wordpress, построенный с помощью visual composer. В ряду находится карусель с элементами. При наведении на блок с элементом он вокруг обрастает красивой тенюшкой, но сверху она обрезается overflow:hidden; который прописан в стандартных стилях owl-carusel. Если overflow просто удалить из стилей, то за контейнером ряда будет отображаться еще 1 товар, что мне абсолютно не в строчку! Такой вопрос: как избавится от обрезки тени? (сайт адаптивный, если что)

```css
/* 
 *  Core Owl Carousel CSS File
 * v1.3.2
 */

/* clearfix */

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
/* display none until init */

.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 100%;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.owl-carousel li {
  list-style: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight {
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  float: left;
}
.owl-controls .owl-page,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
/* mouse grab icon */

.grabbing {
  cursor: url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}
/* fix */

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* shadow */
.product .product-frame {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.10);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.10);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 731px;">
  <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 3040px; left: -380px; display: block; -webkit-transition: all 0ms ease; transition: all 0ms ease;">
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 380px;">
      <li class="...">
        <div class="product-frame ">
          <div class="thumbnail-container ">
            <span class="onfeatured">Featured!</span> 
            <a href="#">
              <div class="front">
                <img width="325" height="325" src="#" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="item-1">
              </div>
            </a>
            <span data-id="3198" class="quick-view">Быстрый просмотр</span>
          </div>
          <!--/ .thumbnail-container-->
          <div class="content-description">
            <div class="product-section">
              <h3><a href="#">ссылка</a></h3>
              <span class="title-description"></span>
              <br>
              <table class="description-table">
              </table>
              <img src="" alt="">
              <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating readonly-rating" data-score="0" title="Not rated yet!" style="width: 100px;">
                  <img src="#" alt="1" title="Not rated yet!">&nbsp;
                  <img src="#" alt="2" title="Not rated yet!">&nbsp;
                  <img src="#" alt="3" title="Not rated yet!">&nbsp;
                  <img src="#" alt="4" title="Not rated yet!">&nbsp;
                  <img src="#" alt="5" title="Not rated yet!">
                  <input type="hidden" name="score" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <span><a class="to-rating" href="#reviews">0 Review(s)</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="process-section">
            <div class="price"><span class="amount">150,000&nbsp;руб.</span>
            </div>
            <a href="/?add-to-cart=3198" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="3198" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Съесть</a> 
            <div class="product-actions">
              <a href="#" class="compare" data-product_id="3198"><span class="feedback">Добавить к сравнению</span>Добавить к сравнению</a> 
            </div>
            <!--/ .product-actions-->
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--/ .product-frame-->
      </li>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В спиппете в вопросе никаких теней не видно.

Comment: @Regent добавил тень

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставь padding-top на размер тени для блока owl-carusel.

Comment: да, padding-top=10px только на li. вопрос решен

Comment: постарайтесь, пожалуйста, писать более развёрнутые ответы. в данном случае пример кода очень бы не помешал.

Comment: хорошо, буду. @Вася закрой тогда вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если `overflow:hidden` нужен в качестве clearfix'а, то следует воспользоваться другой его разновидностью.

Если `overflow:hidden` используется по назначению, то можно сделать wrapper, и во внутренний элемент прописать overflow, а у внешнего сделать тень.

Comment: спасибо, но решение уже было найдено строчкой выше)